# Caracteres Basura en C al copiar a otro archivo

Tags: c, string

Tengo el siguiente problema en C tengo todo que funciona a la perfección me devuelve todo correctamente pero cuando muevo el código o copeo a otro archivo C me imprime datos basura y eso me complica la tarea no entiendo porque es ese problema cuando lo pruebo en su archivo original donde lo realice funciona correctamente sin ningún error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
    
char *valorVariable(char *variable)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen("vsftpd.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        perror("Unable to open file!");
    }
    int cont, bandera = 0;
    char *res = malloc(25 * sizeof(char));
    char *fila = malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
    while ((fgets(fila, 100, fp) != NULL) && bandera <= 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < strlen(fila); i++)
        {
            if (fila[i] == variable[0])
            {
                if (strncmp(&fila[i], variable, strlen(variable)) == 0)
                {
                    fila[strlen(fila)+1] = '\0';
                    for (int j = 0; j < strlen(fila); j++)
                    {
                        if (fila[j] == '=')
                        {
                            for (int a = j + 1; a < strlen(fila)+1; a++)
                            {
                                res[cont] = fila[a];
                                cont++;
                                if (fila[a] == '\0')
                                {
                                    res[cont+1] = '\0';
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return res;
}
int main(void)
{
    char *res = valorVariable("ftpd_banner");
    printf(res);
}
```

Comment: Cuando asigna el puntero para fila y res, no es cierto que contengan 0x00.  Recomiendo que llenelos con 0x00 antes de usar.

Comment: Lo mas probable es que en algún punto estés cayendo en comportamiento indefinido. Seria bueno que compartieras  `vsftpd.txt` para que nosotros podamos copiar, pegar y probar tu código. Así será mas fácil darte una respuesta. Nótese que nunca le das un valor inicial a `cont`, lo mas probable es que el error venga de ahí.

Comment: Tienes que inicializar cont en 0, para que no genere errores de compilación o caracteres basura.

Comment: @Pablochaches e depurado el codigo varias veces y al parecer todo funciona correctamente pero subo el archivo txt para que lo veas y si me ayudas de verdad te lo agradeceria mucho como podria pasarte el archivo txt trato de publicarlo pero contiene varios caracteres que afectan que lo publique aqui.

Comment: @May395 pero cont esta iniciado en 0 o me equivoco

Comment: @JhonHerbas No, `cont` no esta incializado. Si estas en un build de debug puede que se coloque en 0 automaticamente, pero usualmente tendra un valor basura.

Comment: @JhonHerbas Mira a ver si puedes eliminar la parte del archivo que causa problemas al subirlo. O si no es muy grande, podrias probar subir un hexdump.

Comment: @Pablochaches gracias por aclararme lo de cont y lo de subir como hexdump com puedo hacerlo que soy nuevo en esta plataforma